# How to call IEnumerable Collection of Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read the CSV File in chunk in order to avoid the Out of memory Exception issue while importing large CSV file.

I am using IEnumerable Collection approach to read data from csv in chunk and return it to another function.

But I got System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Data.Datatable. Implicit conversion not possible.

Below is code:

```
    public void ImportData(string targetPathwithName, System.Data.DataTable dt1, string targetName)
    {
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        var connection = new SqlConnection(con);



        dt1 =  GetFileData(targetPathwithName, dt1);

        connection.Open();

        var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[" + targetName + "]";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt1);
        bulkCopy.Close();
        connection.Close();

    }

public static IEnumerable<System.Data.DataTable> GetFileData(string sourceFileFullName,  System.Data.DataTable dt1)
    {            
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        var connection = new SqlConnection(con);

        int chunkRowCount = 0;
        int RowCount = 0;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
        {
            if (RowCount != 0)
            {
                string Row = null;
                //Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.                
                while ((Row = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    chunkRowCount++;
                    //var chunkDataTable = ; //Code for filling datatable or whatever  
                    dt1.Rows.Add();

                    if (chunkRowCount == 10000)
                    {
                        chunkRowCount = 0;
                        yield return dt1;
                        dt1 = null;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        int i = 0;

                        foreach (string Cell in Row.Split(','))
                        {
                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Cell))
                            {
                                dt1.Rows[dt1.Rows.Count - 1][i] = DBNull.Value;
                                i = i + 1;
                            }
                            else if (Cell == "00.00.0000")
                            {
                                dt1.Rows[dt1.Rows.Count - 1][i] = DBNull.Value;
                                i = i + 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dt1.Rows[dt1.Rows.Count - 1][i] = Cell;
                                i = i + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            RowCount = RowCount + 1;
        }
            //return last set of data which less then chunk size
            if (null != dt1)                           
                yield return dt1;            
        }
```

How to call IEnumerable Collection of Type System.Data.Datatable in another function?

Comment: are you sure the return type of the function should be `IEnumerable<System.Data.DataTable>`

Comment: @un-lucky Yes , data type should be IEnumerable<System.Data.DataTable> otherwise I wont be able to iterate.

Comment: I think you are going to deal with a single `DataTable` so you wanted to iterate through its DataRow Collection. Then what is the significance for `IEnumerable<DataTable>` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `foreach` loop with some modifications to your code as below:

```
public static void ImportData(string targetPathwithName, System.Data.DataTable dt1, string targetName)
{
    var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    var connection = new SqlConnection(con);

    connection.Open();
    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
    foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in GetFileData(targetPathwithName, dt1))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[" + targetName + "]";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    }
    bulkCopy.Close();
    connection.Close();
}

public static IEnumerable<System.Data.DataTable> GetFileData(string sourceFileFullName, System.Data.DataTable dt1)
{
    var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    var connection = new SqlConnection(con);

    int chunkRowCount = 0;
    //int RowCount = 0;
    string Row;

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
    {
        //if (RowCount != 0) { //this is not meaningful here

        //Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.                
        while ((Row = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            chunkRowCount++;
            //var chunkDataTable = ; //Code for filling datatable or whatever  
            dt1.Rows.Add();

            int i = 0;

            foreach (string Cell in Row.Split(','))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Cell))
                {
                    dt1.Rows[dt1.Rows.Count - 1][i] = DBNull.Value;
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                else if (Cell == "00.00.0000")
                {
                    dt1.Rows[dt1.Rows.Count - 1][i] = DBNull.Value;
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    dt1.Rows[dt1.Rows.Count - 1][i] = Cell;
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }

            if (chunkRowCount == 10000)
            {
                chunkRowCount = 0;
                yield return dt1;
                dt1.Clear(); // = null;
            }

        } //end while

        //}
        //RowCount = RowCount + 1;
    }

    //return last set of data which less then chunk size
    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        yield return dt1;
}
```

i have tested this and it works well

Comment: @rahul16590 so, i think this should be the **accepted answer** ;D) the other answer provided by 'Nikunj' does not use `yield return...` approach you were looking for copy large amount of data. Also, that method consumes a very large amount of RAM memory as you need to keep all data in an  IEnumerableCollection and returns its whole to main function!

Comment: How to yield return datatable if I need to convert the above function to VB.Net

Comment: `Yield` statement is also available in VB.Net 4.5+, see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156729.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are returning a single datatable only and not IEnumerable.

What you could do is 
1) Create a single instance of IEnumerable in the function GetFileData like IEnumerable DTables = new IEnumerable();
2) create a new instance of datatable every time for each chunk of data and add that datatable to the above defined IEnumerableCollection and Then return the Collection.
3) Use for each loop in function ImportData to read through all the datatables in the collection.